# Moment bounds for positive random variables.

Tags: probability

We know that for any random variable $X$, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\geq\mathbb{E}[X]^2$. Assuming that $X$ is a **positive** random variable, is there any other stricter lower bound for $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ (or upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[X]$)?

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is equality for some positive random variables, such as $X=1$, for example, so you cannot improve this for the class of positive variables, because we can approximate the constant function $1$ as close as we wish by positive random variables.

Comment: But what if we have $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\geq f(\text{moments})\geq\mathbb{E}[X]^2$, which are all equal when $X=1$?

Comment: @CLAUDE In general you have $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\text{Var}(X)+\mathbb{E}[X]^2$ if all these are finite and $\text{Var}(X)\ge 0$